# Как упорядочить элементы списка без учета регистра?

Tags: django

Нужно сделать сортировку по алфавиту независимо от регистра. Т.е. "Б" не должно стоять выше, чем "а". Я знаю, что коды прописных букв идут раньше строчных, поэтому нужно саму сортировку вести в нижнем регистре.
Почитал в документации про следующий способ:

```
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

Article.objects.order_by(Lower('name'))
```

Но в итоге такой же результат. Возможно что-то не так сделал. Помогите пожалуйста.

На данный момент использую SQLite (это если вдруг результат от БД зависит).

Comment: Вы видимо совсем новичок. **Lower('name')** - преобразует строку **'name'** к нижнему регистру(которая и без того в нижнем регистре), но ни как не изменяет алгоритм сортировки.

Comment: А я чего-то подумал, что само значение будет переводиться в нижний регистр, а не название поля. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Я видел в живых проектах такое ухищрение: делается еще одно поле, которое постоянно в одном регистре(например, нижнем), например *canonical_[имя поля]*. и этому полю идет сортировка.

В Django можно это поле создавать временно с помощь extra перестроить запрос таким образом:

```
Article.objects.extra(select={'tmp_name': 'lower(name)'}).order_by('tmp_name')
```

-- создается временное поле **tmp_name** у каждой записи и по нему идет сортировка

Comment: Выбивает ошибку:

ambiguous column name: name

Comment: Может тогда на самом деле лишнее поле создать, да и не мучаться с временными полями?